# Использовать переменную как ключ для объекта

Tags: node.js

Что-то вроде:

```
var key = "myKey";
myArray.push( { key : value} );
```

Я знаю, что можно:

```
var key = "myKey";
var obj = {};
obj[key] = value;
myArray.push(obj);
```

Но не подходит, так как мне именно при создании объекта необходимо к ключу обратиться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, в ES6 можно так:

```
var key = "myKey";
myArray.push( { [key] : value} );
```